# Access denied overwriting a file in winrt c#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am trying to overwrite the content of a file but it keeps throwing access denied

```
System.IO.Stream s2 = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForWriteAsync("Assets\\xyz.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s2);
```

How can i make it work?? The exception is

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.<OpenStreamForWriteAsyncCore>d__10.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
  at System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.<OpenStreamForWriteAsyncCore>d__10.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
  at
```

Comment: Why would you *expect* to be able to write into that area? It looks like the sort of area I'd expect to be read-only.

Comment: Please confirm if the file is marked as read-only. Also verify from properties that you have full control on the file

Comment: @SunilAgarwal, i have checked it in the asset folder inside the project folder and the AppX folder inside the bin\debug and in both locations the file is NOT marked read-only

Comment: @JonSkeet, The resource needs to be modified

Comment: @Abi: Why? Why can you not make updates in areas which *are* designed for writing? (I'm trying to find documentation saying that this area is read-only, but I fully expect it to be.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write to the area where the package is installed, by the looks of it. From ["App packages and deployment"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh464929):

> **Windows Store app deployment**
>
> The Windows Store app model is a declarative state-driven process that provides all installation and update data and instructions for an app in a single package. In this declarative model, deployment operations are reliable. The files shipped in the package are immutable, which means that they haven't been modified since they were delivered to the computer. Because the package owner doesn't need to write custom actions and code, the number of failure points are reduced.

If you need to update the assets for all users, it sounds like you should just publish a new version, e.g. via the isolated storage API.

If you need to write user-specific data, you'll need to pick a different location.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write to a location like this:
ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder